# how to use python module return in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a separate Python file that runs some code and returns a dictionary. using lask as my backend, how do I get the return from that function in an `app.route`?

```
get_ticker_info()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", price_dict=price_dict)
```

`get_ticker_info` returns a dictionary called `price_dict` and I have code in my HTML that uses this variable to print it on the page

I tried a few things but nothing works.

Comment: Put the call to `get_ticker_info()` inside `index()` if you need to call it in `index()`.

Comment: `price_dict = get_ticker_info()` Seems straightforward to me.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **price_dict** returned by **get_ticker_info**() in your route, you need to call the function and assign the return value to a variable, which you can then pass to **render_template**() as an argument. Here's an example:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
     price_dict = get_ticker_info()
     return render_template("index.html", price_dict=price_dict)
```

In this code, **get_ticker_info**() is called and the return value is assigned to the **price_dict** variable. This variable is then passed as the **price_dict** argument to **render_template**(), which makes it available to your HTML template. You can then use this variable in your template to display the information contained in the dictionary.

Keep in mind that this code assumes that **get_ticker_info**() is defined in the same file as your Flask route. If it's defined in a separate file, you'll need to import it first before you can call it. You can do this by adding an import statement at the top of your Flask file, like this:

```
from other_file import get_ticker_info
```

This will import the **get_ticker_info** function from the *other_file* module, allowing you to call it in your route.